# How can I see connection information like KDE does?

Tags: unity, 12.04, network-manager

Is there a way I can see download/upload speeds, downloaded/uploaded size, etc. information as KDE network manager shows? I am using 12.04, with Unity and I don't want to install any other software that needs to be opened from dash. I want to see that with the network-manager conection information only.

Answer (score 0):

The `System Monitor` shows network history and speeds, under the *Resources* tab:

[image: system monitor - resources tab]

Comment: So there is nothing I can do to conection information dialog to show this?